# How to convert hex strings to byte values in Java

Tags: java, hex, byte

I have a String array.
I want to convert it to byte array.
I use the Java program.
For example:

```
String str[] = {"aa", "55"};
```

convert to:

```
byte new[] = {(byte)0xaa, (byte)0x55};
```

What can I do?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140131/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-hex-dump-to-a-byte-array-using-java

Comment: `byte n[] = str.getBytes()` will do the task. However, you'll get error on `new` as it is a keyword and cannot be used as identifier.

Comment: @backslashN: Won't the result be like `{97, 97}` and `{53, 53}`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looking at the sample I guess you mean that a string array is actually an array of HEX representation of bytes, don't you?

If yes, then for each string item I would do the following:

1. check that a string consists only of 2 characters
2. these chars are in '0'..'9' or 'a'..'f' interval (take their case into account
   as well)
3. convert each character to a corresponding number, subtracting code value of '0' or 'a'
4. build a byte value, where first char is higher bits and second char is lower ones. E.g.

   ```
   int byteVal = (firstCharNumber << 4) | secondCharNumber;
   ```

Answer (score 54):

```
String str = "Your string";

byte[] array = str.getBytes();
```

Comment: Always specify a specific character set like `UTF-8` unless the default platform dependent character set is adequate (which is undesirable in most cases) using one of the overloaded versions of that method such as `String#getBytes(Charset charset)` or `String#getBytes(String charsetName)`.

Comment: byte[] array = str.getBytes("UTF-8");  throws UnsupportedEncodingException

Answer (score 11):

Convert string to Byte-Array:

```
byte[] theByteArray = stringToConvert.getBytes();
```

Convert String to Byte:

```
 String str = "aa";

 byte b = Byte.valueOf(str);
```

Comment: it gives me `NumberFormatException` when enter a value from `A` to `F`

Answer (score 9):

You can try something similar to this :

```
String s = "65";

byte value = Byte.valueOf(s);
```

Use the `Byte.ValueOf()` method for all the elements in the String array to convert them into Byte values.

Comment: It does not works. java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse 'aa' as integer

Comment: That means it was an empty string

Answer (score 3):

A long way to go :). I am not aware of methods to get rid of long `for` statements

```
ArrayList<Byte> bList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
for(String ss : str) {
    byte[] bArr = ss.getBytes();
    for(Byte b : bArr) {
        bList.add(b);
    }
}
//if you still need an array
byte[] bArr = new byte[bList.size()];
for(int i=0; i<bList.size(); i++) {
    bArr[i] = bList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since there was no answer for **hex string to single byte conversion**, here is mine:

```
private static byte hexStringToByte(String data) {
    return (byte) ((Character.digit(data.charAt(0), 16) << 4)
                  | Character.digit(data.charAt(1), 16));
}
```

Sample usage:

```
hexStringToByte("aa"); // 170
hexStringToByte("ff"); // 255
hexStringToByte("10"); // 16
```

---

Or you can also try the `Integer.parseInt(String number, int radix)` imo, is way better than others.

```
// first parameter is a number represented in string
// second is the radix or the base number system to be use
Integer.parseInt("de", 16); // 222
Integer.parseInt("ad", 16); // 173
Integer.parseInt("c9", 16); // 201
```

Comment: This is the best method for me

Answer (score 2):

```
String source = "testString";
byte[] byteArray = source.getBytes(encoding);
```

You can foreach and do the same with all the strings in the array.

Comment: My mean is change (String)"aa" to (byte)0xaa, but not to (byte)0x97, (byte)0x97

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (using Apache Common Codec):

```
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(str.toCharArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String str[] = {"aa", "55"};

byte b[] = new byte[str.length];

for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    b[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(str[i], 16);
}
```

Integer.parseInt(string, radix) converts a string into an integer, the radix paramter specifies the numeral system.

Use a radix of 16 if the string represents a hexadecimal number.
Use a radix of 2 if the string represents a binary number.
Use a radix of 10 (or omit the radix paramter) if the string represents a decimal number.

For further details check the Java docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String,%20int)

Comment: Code-only answers don't explain why the code works: please add an explanation for future visitors what you did to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here, if you are converting string into byte[].There is a utility code :

```
    String[] str = result.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]","").split(", ");
    byte[] dataCopy = new byte[str.length] ;
    int i=0;
    for(String s:str ) {
        dataCopy[i]=Byte.valueOf(s);
        i++;
    }
    return dataCopy;
```