# Initializing a byte array from hex literals

Tags: java

I have the following problem: I am sending an array to serial port it looks like this

```
 byte arr[] = new byte[]{0x18, 0x1B, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x10,
                         0x21,0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6A, 0x28, 0x1B,0x03}
```

Here comes the problem - I have 3 text fields with R , G , B colors . I get the values from them as String.But I cant convert them to the above format 0xHexValue and put them in the byte array. I've tried a lot of approaches but without any success.

EDIT : I get the values from the text fields of the GUI with txtField.getText() after that there is no problem to convert in example R 200 , G 0 , B 0 to HEX C8 00 00 but I cant insert HEX into my byte array because it's still string . When i try to convert strings to byte with Byte.parseByte(s) some negative values appear....

**EDIT 2** Byte.valueOf(myString) gets an exception on value 200

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: Value out of range. Value:"200"
>   Radix:10

**GUYS:** I see your posts and I suggest to focus on this : How to make in example this String **"C8"** to fit in the **arr[]** with the proper format **0xC8** and of course as byte not as String...

Comment: How are the values stored in the string? "0x18", "18", ...?

Comment: Can you please show us how you tried it?

Comment: Byte.parseByte(string,radix);

Comment: (Note that you'd need to somehow strip off the "0x" first, before using parseByte.)

Comment: Possibly see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652804/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-in-java), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652804/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-in-java).

Answer (score 2):

Use [Byte.parseByte](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#parseByte%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

```
Byte.parseByte(inputString,16);
```

16 is hexadecimal radix

---

You can also use [Byte.decode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29)

```
Byte.decode(inputString);//inputString can be decimal, hexadecimal, and octal numbers
```

Comment: What do you assume the `input` to be in OP's case ?

Comment: Please mention what sort of `String` i.e. contents of the string.

Comment: @TheNewIdiot it could be anything "0x", "0X", "#", or leading zero

Comment: Not for me , please add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    List<Byte> byteList = new ArrayList<>();
    String data = "0x18, 0x1B, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF, 0x01, 0x10,0x21,0x30, 0x00, 0x00, 0x6A, 0x28, 0x1B,0x03";
    Pattern hexPattern = Pattern.compile("0x(..)");
    Matcher matcher = hexPattern.matcher(data);

    while(matcher.find()) {
        byteList.add((byte)Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1), 16));
    }

    System.out.println(">>> " + byteList);
```

You can change the `byteList` by an actual byte array. Also, I'm assuming that you have your String in a certain way, but the idea is this one.