# String to byte in java

Tags: java, string, byte

I have a problem in converting `String` (contains hexadecimal value) to `byte`. Like below code.

```
String hexaString = "0xA1";
byte hexaByte = (byte)hexaString;
```

Not able to convert from String to byte like this code (Getting the Error : `Cannot cast from String to byte`).

But i am able to do like this

```
byte hexaByte = (byte)0xA1; //this is giving output as -95
```

Anyone please guide me how can i do like the first method(this also output the value -95). Because, the last two digit i will get from db and i need to convert it to hexadecimal(appending 0x). Then i should send to client as a byte value.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: hexaString.getBytes() ? :)

Comment: @Shark looks like the `OP` is trying to convert the value as a whole

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert string to byte in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652804/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-in-java)

Comment: @Shark , hexaString.getBytes()  this will give byte array. I want to convert the value as a whole like Reimeus said

Comment: I understand the problem, but it works-around the inability to cast Strings to bytes. Try to use unsigned bytes/ints before casting to integers.

I'll dig out some of my Java code-gems that deal with bytes when I get home unless you solve it before I do :)

@Reimeus thanks for helping (him) out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
byte hexaByte = Byte.parseByte("1A", 16);
```

where 16 is radix (base of system numeration), but if the number is higer than 127 it will cause NumberFormatException.

Comment: i tried this with "A1" value. it is giving exception

Comment: Becouse A1 in hexadecimal is 161 in decimal and it's higer than 127.

Comment: Yoy can try:  byte hexaByte = (byte)Integer.parseInt("A1", 16); But it returns wrong value -95

Comment: It needs to parse it as unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to be able to work with the 0x prefix, `(byte) Integer.decode("0xA1")` will do the right thing.