# turn my 32 character int into a 32 byte array as is in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte

I am wondering how can I turn my 32 character int into a 32-byte array as it is represented.

Example:

I have this int:

```
int test = 123456789;
```

And I want to turn it into this:

```
byte[] Write_Page_Four = new byte[] {  

                                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
                                (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x23, (byte) 0x45,
                                (byte) 0x67, (byte) 0x89};
```

Currently, I'm thinking of splitting my int by 2 and just manually assigning them to the byte array but I am having some troubles in doing so, and I believe that this is not the best practice for my problem.

This is what I have ATM, which is returning error and still work on progress though and I could use some advice on it:

```
String test2 = "01";
String test1 = "0x"+test2; 
byte test =  Byte.valueOf(test1);
System.out.println("teeeeest-----"+test);

byte[] Write_Page_Four = new byte[] {(byte) test};
```

And this one is returning an error:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x01"

Comment: This number is way too large to be represented by an `int` (32 bits). Apart from that, do you want to the `byte[]` to represent the text, or the bytes of the actual `int`?

Comment: @Paul ooops you're right, I should make it clear that only 9 digits of int would be use the rest of the leading numbers are 0. so sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of processing the textual representation of the number I'd recommend to simply calculate the single numbers:

Get two digits of the number each time:

```
int inp = 1234...;

for(int lowerBound = 1 ; lowerBound < Integer.MAX_VALUE ; lowerBound *= 100)
    //twoDigit contains two digits of the input-number
    int twoDigit = (inp /lowerBound) % 100;
```

Transform these two digits into a byte:

```
byte transform(int i){
    if(i == 0)
        return 0x00;

    int lsd = (i % 10); //least significant digit of the input (decimal)
    int msd = (i / 10); //most significant digit

    //merge lsd and msd into a single number, where the lower 4 bits are reserved for
    //lsd and the higher 4 bits for msd
    return lsd | (msd << 4);
}
```

The complete code would look like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class test
{
    private static final int BYTES = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int v = 12345678;

        int at_arr = BYTES - 1;
        byte[] result = new byte[BYTES];//int is 32-bit/4 byte long

        for(int lowerBound = 1 ; lowerBound < Integer.MAX_VALUE && at_arr > -1; lowerBound *= 100, at_arr--)
            result[at_arr] = transformDigits((v / lowerBound) % 100);

        for(byte b : result)
            System.out.print(" 0x" + Integer.toString(b , 16) + ",");
        System.out.println();
    }

    static byte transformDigits(int i){
        if(i == 0)
            return 0x00;

        int lsd = (i % 10); //least significant digit of the input (decimal)
        int msd = (i / 10); //most significant digit

        //merge lsd and msd into a single number, where the lower 4 bits are reserved for
        //lsd and the higher 4 bits for msd
        return (byte) (lsd | (msd << 4));
    }
}
```

This code can be used basically for any integral type, if the types and value of `BYTES` are updated appropriately.

Comment: Mind that the OP is having trouble between number systems. `1234...` will not generate `0x12,0x34,...` simply because it is interpreted decimally whereas the OP wants to interpret it hexadecimally. +1 nevertheless.

Comment: @CommuSoft OP wants to transform an `int` into the raw bytes representing it. I just presented a **way** more efficient way to do this transformation than converting to text and parsing back.

Comment: What would be a non-lazy way of doing this? as I plan to implement a satisfactory solution, not a duct tape solution.

Comment: @makingitwork i think i understood the question now. I'll edit the post, my solution won't even work for what you want.

Comment: @makingitwork sry for the bugs, ive corrected everything, the final version has correct output. Except for the fact that the output doesn't exactly look nice and `0x00` is outputted as `0x0`.

Comment: In this part of the code `for(byte b : result)
            System.out.print(" 0x" + Integer.toString(b , 16) + ",");` I changed it to: `for(byte b : result){
                                tarr[x] = "0x" + Integer.toString(b , 16);
                                System.out.println(tarr[x]);
                                x++;   
                            }` and I got a nullpointerexception error at the array part. i declared the array as `String[] tarr = null;`

Comment: @makingitwork if `tarr` is `null`, you can't assign anything to it. And why would you even need a `String[]` anyways? Either use `String[] tarr = new String[BYTES];` or leave the `String[]` completely away.

Answer (score 3):

## What is causing problems

`Byte.valueOf` doesn't parse data like the Java compiler does: it expects as input as a decimal number.

What you can use however, is `Byte.valueOf(String,int)` with an arbitrary radix. In that case you can solve it using:

```
byte test =  Byte.valueOf(test2,16); //using test2, not test1
```

Mind that should not add `"0x"` in the front. Nevertheless this is an inefficient way to do this.

## Ints are 32-bits, not 32-bytes

A second problem is that you state that you can store a number like `12345678901234567890123456789011` into an int. You cannot. An `int` has 32 **bits**. This means its representation is limited to more or less 2.1B. So I think you mean you store `12345678901234567890123456789011` in a `String`?

## Number systems

Mind that the number `12345678901234567890123456789011` is not represented internally as `(byte) 0x12, (byte) 0x34,...` unless you are working with *binary coded decimals*. This is because a computer uses the binary number system (and thus groups bytes with the hexadecimal representation), whereas humans use the decimal representation. `123456789` for instance will be represented as `0x07,0x5B,0xCD 0x15`.

## Serializing an int (or other datastructure) using an array of bytes

You can convert an `int` (and other datatypes) into an array of bytes using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1936865/67579):

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(test);
byte[] result = b.array(); //result will be 4 bytes,
//since you can represent any int with four bytes.
```

Or, in case you want to represent the `int` like the way you do this, you could use the following method:

```
int t = test;
byte[] dat = new byte[5];//at most 5 bytes needed
for(int j = 4; test != 0; j--) {
    int rm = t%100;
    dat[j] = (byte) (rm%10+((rm/10)<<8));
    t /= 100;
}
//result is dat
```

Comment: @makingitwork: still it is not completely clear. Mind that a byte represents numbers between `0` and (including) `255`. So you can represent it more effeciently (and a computer does this, because it makes additions, etc. more efficient as well). `123456789` is for instance the equivalent of `0x75bcd15`.

Comment: What would your suggested solution be for this kind of problem?

Comment: I meant the confusion regarding the whole int value, I did miss that :D, regarding my question as stated I want to be able to present my int value into a byte value as is, that is why I tried appending 0x to my int, I do understand that converting string to byte will result in a very different outcome as each character has a different byte representation. that is why I was hoping that I could simply append 0x to my number and make it look like a byte data already.

Comment: @makingitwork: well string manipulations are tend to be very inefficient. In order to serialize an `int` to a `byte[]` I recommend using the `ByteBuffer` or Andreas's solution (which is semantically equivalent). It will result in a fixed number of bits and a smaller number of bits. Furthermore it prevents one from *reinventing the wheel*.

Comment: What I mean in my question is not to convert but to copy, took me a while to realize this. :D and I found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652804/how-to-convert-string-to-byte-in-java) though I cannot understand the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to convert an `int` to a `byte[]`:

```
int test = 123456789;

byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
bytes[0] = (byte)(test >> 24);
bytes[1] = (byte)(test >> 16);
bytes[2] = (byte)(test >> 8);
bytes[3] = (byte)test;

System.out.printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x%n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

*Output*

```
07 5b cd 15
```

You can also inline it, if you want:

```
int test = 123456789;
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { (byte)(test >> 24),
                            (byte)(test >> 16),
                            (byte)(test >> 8),
                            (byte)test };
System.out.printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x%n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);
```

Comment: This is indeed how you *should* serialize an `int`. The problem is that the OP seems to have a different format in mind. +1 anyway.

Comment: @CommuSoft Yeah, that's why I show the result, since it deviates from question. You got my +1 for providing both an easier version of this, and an alternate following question more literally (even though that makes little sense to me).